# "I didn't go to the office yesterday". "I didn't go to work yesterday"

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, definite-article, grammaticality-in-context

> I didn't go to the office yesterday.
> I didn't go to work yesterday.

Why is the article 'the' omitted in the second sentence.

Comment: Does [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16702/late-for-school-or-late-for-the-school) answer your question?

Comment: Because "work" in that sense is a noncount noun, much like when we say, "I didn't go to school yesterday," "I didn't go to lunch yesterday," "I didn't go to karate yesterday," etc. In each instance, it refers to a scheduled activity at a specified locale, not just a locale. I'd put this as an answer, but as @CanadianYankee pointed out, this exact question has already been answered so many times already (e.g., https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243595/why-to-go-to-work-and-school-without-the ) that it's likely to get flagged and deleted, I feel.